# Issue with opening the right path for file dialog

Tags: image, ms-access, filedialog

i am using vba access 2010 and have a simple form, a button control. the idea is to create a folder and after which use the filedialog to open up the folder i just created. i am able to create the folder, but how do i open up to the path i just created? below will be the code i have, will really really appreciate it if anyone can help. thanks in advance

Option Compare Database

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

 Dim Foldername As String
 Foldername = "\\server\Instructions\"

 MkDir ("C:\Users\Stanley\Desktop\New folder\123")


 setProfilePicture
End Sub
```

'----------------------image path setting---------------------

```
Private Sub setProfilePicture()

'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object.
    Dim fd As FileDialog

    'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Declare a variable to contain the path
    'of each selected item. Even though the path is a String,
    'the variable must be a Variant because For Each...Next
    'routines only work with Variants and Objects.
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

    'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
    With fd


    'Change the contents of the Files of Type list.
    'Empty the list by clearing the FileDialogFilters collection.
    .Filters.Clear

    'Add a filter that includes all files.
    .Filters.Add "All files", "*.*"

    'Add a filter that includes GIF and JPEG images and make it the first item in the list.
    .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg", 1

    'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
    'The user pressed the action button.
    If .Show = -1 Then

    'Step through each String in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.
    For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems

    'vrtSelectedItem is a String that contains the path of each selected item.
    'You can use any file I/O functions that you want to work with this path.
    'This example simply displays the path in a message box.
    'MsgBox "Path name: " & vrtSelectedItem
    Me.ImagePerson.Picture = vrtSelectedItem
    'Me.TextboxPersonFilepath.Value = "File path: " & vrtSelectedItem
    Next vrtSelectedItem
    'The user pressed Cancel.
    Else
    End If
    End With

    'Set the object variable to Nothing.
    Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

'-----------------end of image path setting--------------

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a variable.

In your Command0_Click sub, set your directory as a variable, like

```
X = "MyPath To My Folder"
```

Then, call setProfilePicture(X)

In setProfilePicture, set it up like:

```
Private Sub setProfilePicture(MyDir as String)
```

Then MyDir is now the path to your folder, and you can use it as a variable in your sub